# UserDefaults and If/else Erratic behavior

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'll try to explain the best I can the issue(s) Im having:
I have a todo list with two viewcontrollers, you will see in the code below a few print for the debug and I added a "erase" (erase userdefault) and check (check whats stored in userDefaults) for debugging

I begin by clearing my userDefaults with Erase and can see the value is "nil".
I then add an item to my list eg car and it works fine.
Then I add a second item like apple, sometimes it works but 90% of the time it just replaces car instead of adding to the array; I can see that with the check button.

So I end up with my first issue where the if loop only replaces the previous value BUT with the print function I can see that it is the first part of the loop executing as I can see "first" in the console so it should add to the array???

Many times from a "clear"; adding the first two items to my list work but from the second the if function always replaces the last item with the new one; keeping the previous ones.

If I clear my data and get a nil value for my UserDefaults value and I can can still see that the first part of the loop is executing instead of the else

Sometime I restart the IOS simulator and get a value stored out of nowhere

Now Im thinking there is a bug with "toDo" identifier and change all ID to "list" and only the else loop is executing !!!

I don't see why my code is so messed up. I hope I was clear enough; thanks for reading

Here is my code below (two viewcontrollers; one for adding items and the other for the tableView)

First ViewController

```
var toDoStorage = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "toDo")
var toDoList = [String] ()

@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var reportLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "toDo") as Any)
}

@IBAction func eraseButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let eraseDate = ""
    UserDefaults.standard.set(eraseDate, forKey: "toDo")
    print(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "toDo") as Any)
   }

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let tempArray = toDoStorage as? [String]{
        toDoList = tempArray
        print("first")
        toDoList.append(itemLabel.text!)

    } else {
        toDoList = [itemLabel.text!]
        print("else")
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "toDo")
    itemLabel.text = ""
}
```

second

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

var toDo = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "toDo") ?? [String]()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return toDo.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "IDCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: toDo[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        toDo.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.reloadData()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(toDo, forKey: "toDo")
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let dataCheck = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "toDo")
    if let newData = dataCheck as? [String] {
        toDo = newData
        table.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer as posted below (replaced toDo with list in my new project)

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "list") as? [String] != nil {
        toDoList = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "list")!
        toDoList.append(itemLabel.text!)

    } else {
        toDoList = [itemLabel.text!]
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "list")
    itemLabel.text = String()
    toDoList = [String] ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OURRAY after 2 days on it I debugged myself for the first time ever !!! :D
So the issue was mainly with the if statement on two things: 1) my condition was not returning any value because I did not add a comparator at the end then 2) in the first part I was not updating the array before adding to it. Here is the new code below:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "list") as? [String] != nil {
        toDoList = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "list")!
        toDoList.append(itemLabel.text!)
    } else {
        toDoList = [itemLabel.text!]
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "list")
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for key `toDo` is an array of strings. To clear the array in `func eraseButton` replace

```
let eraseDate = ""
```

with

```
let eraseDate = [String]()
```

Comment: did the change you suggested, pressed erase and got Optional([]) as print value. added a new value and got "first" in print value for the loop and 
"Optional(["apple", "trek", "dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg"])" so the data did not get erased; the if loop did not trigger the else statement as it should and I got back the data before erasing. Im going officially insane :D

Comment: Don't use two separate arrays. `toDoStorage` is quasi a constant. Write `if let tempArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "toDo") as? [String] {` in `func saveButton`

Comment: yes that makes sense; removed the toDoStorage and added your code. But things are getting weirder: compiled the code and I got test values from a long time before like "4" and "cheese" !! then I add a new value and same as before it erases/replace the last value in the array instead of adding... Im really beginning to think there is a bug with Xcode... Using the latest xcode-beta

Comment: found it, check my new post answer

Comment: Your answer is practically the same as my answer and the suggestion in the comment.

Comment: your suggestion helped getting on track to find the definitive answer, please upvote the answer

Comment: If you *did not add a comparator at the end* then you didn't use my `if let` suggestion which is supposed to solve the issue.

Comment: how do you call != nil then ? I tried your suggestion before and it did not work as I wrote earlier

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're switching between `String` and an `[String]` for the object that corresponds to the "toDo" key.

Try changing the empty String to an empty array i.e. `[]` and see if that clears up some issues.

Comment: found it, check new answer